# How do I save a image using a flask API then return it to my React App can use it

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, file-upload

I am trying to use my Flask API to save an image to the database OR just a file system but this is something I have never done and am getting nowhere with it.

I would like to be able to return the image back when the route is called and be able to use it in my ReactJS Application using just a img tag.

All I have been able to find is how to save the image to the Database and then download it using a route. I need to be able to return it. (It works just not what I need.)

Here is what that was:

```
    @app.route('/img-upload', methods=['POST'])
def img_upload():
    file = request.files['image']

    newFile = Mealplan(name=file.filename, data=file.read())

    db.session.add(newFile)
    db.session.commit()

    return jsonify({"Done!" : "The file has been uploaded."})

@app.route('/get-mealplan-image/<given_mealplan_id>')
def download_img(given_mealplan_id):
    file_data = MealPlan.query.filter_by(id=given_mealplan_id).first()
    return send_file(BytesIO(file_data.data), attachment_filename=file_data.name, as_attachment=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the files on the file system will be a more proper method. Here is a minimal example:

```
from flask import send_from_directory

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
uploads_path = os.path.join(basedir, 'uploads')  # assume you have created a uploads folder


@app.route('/img-upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload_image():

    f = request.files['image']
    f.save(os.path.join(uploads_path , f.filename))  # save the file into the uploads folder

    newFile = Mealplan(name=f.filename)  # only save the filename to database
    db.session.add(newFile)
    db.session.commit()

    return jsonify({"Done!" : "The file has been uploaded."})


@app.route('/images/<path:filename>')
def serve_image(filename):
    return send_from_directory(uploads_path, filename)  # return the image
```

In your React app, you can use the filename to build to the image URL: `/images/hello.jpg`

Update:

If you can only get the id, the view function will be similar:

```
@app.route('/get-mealplan-image/<given_mealplan_id>')
def download_img(given_mealplan_id):
    file_data = MealPlan.query.filter_by(id=given_mealplan_id).first()
    return send_from_directory(uploads_path, file_data.name)
```

Comment: How can I use the id stored in the database as the filename? I just dont know how to do this as I dont think it saves the file extension when I query and just the id of the query.

Comment: You can query the filename with the id, check the update.

Comment: When building the image url is it just like a standard website url or do I use url_for ?

Comment: Both works, but I would recommend using `url_for` instead hard-encoding the URL.

Comment: how would I do that with an image tag I’ve only seen the url_for I have never used it

Comment: Could you describe it more clearly? I don't understand what you mean. If you can't use `url_for` in the front application (i.e. you didn't use Jinja), you can just hard-code the URL and fill the id part.